# Constructing sequences whose sets of subsequential limits are $\Bbb R$ and $[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, general-topology, limits

I need to give four examples of sequences in $\Bbb R$ whose sets of subsequential limits are the empty set, $\Bbb Z,$ the interval $[0,1]$, and $\Bbb R$.

The first one is obvious because $a_n=n$ has no subsequential limits.

For the second one, there may be a simpler way to do it, but I defined   $b_n =
\begin{cases}
0,  & \text{else} \\
1,  & \text{if $n=2^k$} \\
-1, & \text{if $n=3^k$} \\
2, & \text{if $n=5^k$} \\
-2, & \text{if $n=7^k$} \\
\cdot\cdot\cdot, & \text{if $n=p^k$ where $p$ is the next prime}
\end{cases}$

For the third and fourth cases, I don't really know where to begin. I assume I need to utilize the fact that $\Bbb Q$ is dense in $\Bbb R.$

Answer (score 1):

For $\mathbb R$ just arrange all rational numbers in  sequence and for $[0,1]$ arrange all rational numbers belonging to $[0,1]$ in a sequence.